# How to check if the current routing parameters has been modified using Angular Routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Initially, when I'm landing on the home page of the application based on the current routing link I'm taking the router params and passing as an argument to API to fetch data, this call should be made on OnInit and from next time whenever the user changes the route I have to call different function based on the router params to send it to backend . I have to call a function only when the router resource URI has been changed. Please help me to find out like how to check the router link has been changed or not.

Code used to take the current router params in @ngOnInit not sure how to check the condition for whenever the router params have been changed.

```
 this.route.params.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe(params => {

      this.resourceURI = params['resourceURI'];
      this.fetchDataOnInit(this.resourceURI);
    });
```

// Some conditions has to be checked here and call some other function from second time which im not aware like how to try .

Comment: You r subscribing to an observable, this means anytime the params change this subscription should result in a value emitted by the observable. This value is broadcasted to all observers, like your component in ngOnInit. Try ```console.log(params);``` in your subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [first()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/first.html) operator to select the first value, and use [skip(1)](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/skip.html) to skip over the first value.

```js
   const resourceURI$ = this.route.params.pipe(pluck('resourceURI'));

   // handle first emitted value
   resourceURI$.pipe(
       first(),
       takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
   ).subscribe(resourceURI => {
       this.resourceURI = resourceURI;
       this.fetchDataOnInit(resourceURI);
   });

   // skip first emitted value
   resourceURI$.pipe(
       distinctUntilChanged(),
       skip(1),
       takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
   ).subscribe(resourceURI => {
       // do work with second, third, forth, etc..
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have to make the first call only one once which is in OnInit and from second time whenever I'm changing the routing params I have to make the second call. Here how can I check if there's a difference between first resource URI and the second resource URI?

Comment: @AD_SK I've updated the answer. You listen only for distinct values. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html

Comment: but here I'm seeing that first call is happening again, I have to skip the first function when the router has been changed and call only the second function.